# Double braces while creating index with certain length in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

To create index with certain length I use the following query:

```
CREATE INDEX users_full_name_idx ON users ((full_name::varchar(16)));
```

This code works fine. However, if I try to do the following:

```
CREATE INDEX users_full_name_idx ON users (full_name::varchar(16));
```

I get error. Could anyone explain why we need two braces but not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [index on expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-expressional.html):

> An index column need not be just a column of the underlying table, but can be a function or scalar expression computed from one or more columns of the table. This feature is useful to obtain fast access to tables based on the results of computations.
>
> ```
> CREATE INDEX test1_lower_col1_idx ON test1 (lower(col1));
>
> CREATE INDEX people_names ON people ((first_name || ' ' || last_name));
> ```
>
> **The syntax of the CREATE INDEX command normally requires writing parentheses around index expressions, as shown in the second example.** The parentheses can be omitted when the expression is just a function call, as in the first example.

and [CREATE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createindex.html):

> The key field(s) for the index are specified as column names, **or alternatively as expressions written in parentheses**.